# Cross compile xalan-c 1.11, arm gcc, CodeSourcery 4.3.3, ./configure

Tags: arm, cross-platform, configure, xalan, codesourcery

I have been trying to compile xalan-c specifically 1.11 with xerces 3.1.1. with an arm cross-compile toolchain 4.3.3 from CodeSourcery on a ubuntu 14.x 64.

xalan-c has two configure scripts. First the usual ./configure and second ./runConfigure.

Up until now I have been cross-compiling other libs (e.g. libusb-1.0/libusb-0.1/openssl) with

```
--host../configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix="/home/user/sysroot-arm-sf/usr/local/"
```

This time however I believe I need to use ./runConfigure otherwise some environment variables are not set (e.g. how it deals with messages) 
I use:

```
./runConfigure -p linux -x arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -P "/home/user/sysroot-arm-sf/usr/local/"  -C--host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
```

instead which I believe to be the equivalent to ./configure . the ./runConfigure is using all default values (except for the c and c++ compiler which it does not recognize, unfortunately)

```
Generating makefiles with the following options ...
Platform: linux
C Compiler: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
C++ Compiler: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
Extra compile options: 
Extra link options: 
Transcoder: default
Localization system: inmem
Locale: en_US
Thread option: pthread
bitsToBuild option: 32
Extra configure options:  --prefix=/home/user/sysroot-arm-sf/usr/local/ --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
Debug is OFF
I do not recognize the C compiler 'arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc'. Continuing anyway ...
I do not recognize the C++ compiler 'arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++'. Continuing anyway ...

configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++... arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for autoconf... autoconf
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-none-linux-gnueabi
checking for floor in -lm... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for mbstowcs... yes
checking if mbstowcs can count only... cross-compiling default
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile.incl
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/xalanc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/xalanc/Utils/Makefile
config.status: creating src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/Makefile
config.status: creating src/xalanc/Utils/XalanMsgLib/Makefile
config.status: creating samples/Makefile
config.status: creating Tests/Makefile

If the result of the above commands look OK to you, go to the directory
/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/ and type "gmake" or "make" to make the XALAN-C system.

Note: You must use GNU make to use the Xalan Makefile.
```

Then I'll try

```
make
make -C src/xalanc all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc'
Preparing the directory structure for a build ...
mkdir -p ../../obj
mkdir -p ../../lib
mkdir -p ../../bin
make -C Utils prepare
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/Utils'
mkdir -p ../../../nls
mkdir -p ../../../nls/include
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/Utils'
make -C Utils locale
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/Utils'
make -C MsgCreator 
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  -pthread -D_REENTRANT   -Wall -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DXALAN_INMEM_MSG_LOADER -c -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//include -I../../../../nls/include -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//src/ -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/xercesc -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/  -o ../../../../obj/MsgFileOutputStream.o /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/MsgFileOutputStream.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  -pthread -D_REENTRANT   -Wall -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DXALAN_INMEM_MSG_LOADER -c -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//include -I../../../../nls/include -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//src/ -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/xercesc -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/  -o ../../../../obj/ICUResHandler.o /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/ICUResHandler.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  -pthread -D_REENTRANT   -Wall -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DXALAN_INMEM_MSG_LOADER -c -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//include -I../../../../nls/include -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//src/ -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/xercesc -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/  -o ../../../../obj/InMemHandler.o /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/InMemHandler.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  -pthread -D_REENTRANT   -Wall -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DXALAN_INMEM_MSG_LOADER -c -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//include -I../../../../nls/include -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//src/ -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/xercesc -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/  -o ../../../../obj/MsgCreator.o /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/MsgCreator.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  -pthread -D_REENTRANT   -Wall -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DXALAN_INMEM_MSG_LOADER -c -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//include -I../../../../nls/include -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//src/ -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/xercesc -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/  -o ../../../../obj/NLSHandler.o /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/NLSHandler.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  -pthread -D_REENTRANT   -Wall -fPIC -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DXALAN_INMEM_MSG_LOADER -c -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src -I/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//include -I../../../../nls/include -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//src/ -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/xercesc -I/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//include/  -o ../../../../obj/SAX2Handler.o /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/SAX2Handler.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -DLINUX -fPIC -pthread -D_REENTRANT -DXALAN_INMEM_MSG_LOADER   \
     -lm  -lpthread  ../../../../obj/MsgFileOutputStream.o ../../../../obj/ICUResHandler.o ../../../../obj/InMemHandler.o ../../../../obj/MsgCreator.o ../../../../obj/NLSHandler.o ../../../../obj/SAX2Handler.o -o ../../../../bin/MsgCreator -L/home/user/xerces-c-3.1.1//lib -lxerces-c 
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator'
../../../bin/MsgCreator /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/NLS/en_US/XalanMsg_en_US.xlf -TYPE inmem -LOCALE en_US
../../../bin/MsgCreator: ../../../bin/MsgCreator: cannot execute binary file
make[2]: *** [../../../nls/include/LocalMsgData.hpp] Error 126
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/Utils'
make[1]: *** [locale] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and it will fail executing

```
../../../bin/MsgCreator /home/user/xalan-c-1.11/c//src/xalanc/NLS/en_US/XalanMsg_en_US.xlf -TYPE inmem -LOCALE en_US
```

which is

```
bin/MsgCreator: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.14, not stripped
```

a binary for an Arm arch. I though ./runConfigure had used the --host option and was aware this was a cross build. Or maybe this is something xalan-c specific?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following workaround which apparently worked.

The files in the xalanc bin/ Folder seem to be only used at compile time (at least I guessed so). Xalan generates headerfiles etc. in order to compile the libxalanMsg.so .

It was a long shot but I simply precompile those bin/ files for Ubuntu x86 and copied those files into my cross compile bin folder.

done. (at least for now)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is really tough and weird. Fortunately, I find a way to resolve this problem.
From the error, we can conclude that the build process uses an executable tool named 'MsgCreator'.

### **Where is it from?**

Actually, this tool is an intermediate product of the build process. Xalan generate it and use this tool to do something he wants.

### **What happens?**

You may remember that you are now cross-compiling Xalan, so the target executable platform of MsgCreator may not support your build platform. This case will cause the error you see.

### **How to solve this problem**

1. Use the local compiler to build a local MsgCreator which means this tool can run on your build platform.
2. Update the code in …./xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/Malefile.in.
   $(XSL_BIN_DIR)/MsgCreator -> $(XSL_BIN_TMP_DIR)/MsgCreator
3. Export XSL_BIN_TMP_DIR to your local MsgCreator tool path.
4. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add MsgCreator dependency libraries. These libraries can be generated by compiling Xerces-C (the version must greater than 3.0) with your local compiler.
5. Cross compile Xalan, everything will go well.

Comment: This approach works for Windows ARM as well with CMake file

Answer (score 0):

It does say

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
```

So this looks like a poorly tested makefile, to me.

You could try to debug it, or you could just install [qemu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qemu) so that ARM binaries magically Just Work (assuming they can find their libraries).

Comment: Thanks for answering that quickly, I'll try to setup _qemu_.